# PHP - If String Contains

Tags: php

Ok, So I have `if(!empty($_GET['s']) && strpos($_GET['s'],'tt') !== false) {`

Which is all good if they do ?s=ttBlaBla they are all good,

But because of what my page does if they go directly to ?s=tt or ?s=BlaBla its a very bad thing.

how can I get it to make sure tt is in $_GET['s'] but check that its not on its own?

Becuase strpos only checks if its actually in the string anywhere so using $strpos wont work at least to my knowledge it wont.

Comment: You could do a `strlen($_GET['s']) > 2` in that test as well

Comment: RiggsFolly as in a replacement to !empty($_GET['s']) && strpos($_GET['s'],'tt'?

Comment: No `if(!empty($_GET['s']) && strpos($_GET['s'],'tt') !== false && strlen($_GET['s']) > 2`)

Comment: That wouldnt be great cause they could just do ?s=ttt or ?s=blabla still, Thx doe but I already got my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Add another check then

```
&& $_GET['s']!='tt'
```

Comment: Good, But remember it cant have just tt and it cant just have BlaBla, and BlaBla could be anything the user enters.

Comment: what about use of preg_match?

Comment: Wait hanky, Just having this: `if(!empty($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']!='tt' && strpos($_GET['s'],'tt') !== false) {` works perfect it bans having just blabla and also bans just having tt thank you :)